# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.DELETE }

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to write a code that shows a list of apps and lets the user choose an app to delete. I wrote this code based on what i've seen online:

```
appListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Uri packageUri = Uri.parse(names.get(position));
                Intent uninstallIntent =
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageUri);
                startActivity(uninstallIntent);
            }
        });
```

However, for some reason I am getting this exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.UNINSTALL_PACKAGE dat=com.ivuu }
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".AppList"></activity>
</application>
```

I am pretty new to android and I spent the whole day on this... Please tell me what I am missing

Thanks

Comment: Add uninstall permission also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not have a scheme. Your `Uri` needs to be of the form `package:...`, where `...` is the application ID/package name.